# Multiple User extended objects in django

Tags: python, django, models

Can we use multiple user extended objects in the same app for eg I have a model Teachers and other students in my app with both of them related to User by oneToone field but with some different extended properties so can anyone plz tell me how to configure this using User property and declaring both as AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE also instead of defining a complete function in models of get_or_create() like

```
    def get_or_create_profile(user):
            user.profile, c = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return user.profile
```

I am using a function like

```
    User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = u)[0])
```

but this still isn't working so so there is any problem with the defining functions or I have to also use something more ....

models.py looks like this

```
    class Teachers(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        department = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        .....
        .....

    class Students(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        enrollment_no = models.IntegerField()
        ......
        ......
```

Comment: Can you paste the your Model, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to `Can we use multiple user extended objects in the same app?` is **No**

The answer to  `So can anyone please tell me how to configure this using User property?`

Maybe this can Work

```
................. #User Code

 ## this function mus be into your custom User#########3

   @property
   def profile(self):
       return UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=self)
```

Not tested yet, but this must work

Comment: thanks for the answer isn't its possible to use any sort of related_name concept as used with multiple foreign keys..

Comment: Yeah you can do it :)

Comment: But how I means thats what I am asking in this question about what are the args or functions in django that could be used to implement this